# What is the reason of null pointer exception?

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener

I am a beginner in Android programming. I am writing a simple code in which after clicking a button in main activity, it opens second activity. But the app isn't opening in emulator and in logcat I am continuously getting null pointer exception. Please help me to rectify this.

MainActivity.java

```
      package com.example.whyprocastinate;

      import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
      import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.LayoutInflater;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
      import android.widget.Button;

      public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    this.setClickListener();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
  }

  private void setClickListener(){
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSecondActivity();  
        }
    }); 
  }

    private void startSecondActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnterTask.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
 }

 @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  /**
  * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
  */
  public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
      }
   }

  }`
```

Here's what logcat is showing

---

```
07-09 02:18:27.673: W/dalvikvm(1082): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0xb2b02ba8)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082): Process: com.example.whyprocastinate, PID: 1082
07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.whyprocastinate/com.example.whyprocastinate.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at com.example.whyprocastinate.MainActivity.setClickListener(MainActivity.java:33)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at com.example.whyprocastinate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

07-09 02:18:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     ... 11 more

07-09 02:18:31.023: I/Process(1082): Sending signal. PID: 1082 SIG: 9`
```

Line 33 in MainActivity.java is

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
```

Fragement_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context="com.example.whyprocastinate.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:text="@string/heading" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="+"        
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/heading"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"               
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

'EnterTask' is the secondActivity. It's a blank activity and I haven't added any code in it.

Comment: What is `this.setClickListener()` ?

Comment: The button is in your MainActivity Layout or the FragmentLayout ?

Comment: setClickListener() is the method in which I am adding Click Listener to the button

Comment: Button is in MainActivity Layout

Comment: Can you show `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: Double check where the button is coming from I think Nullpointer throws because you referenced the wrong button and thats why it triggered in onClick()

Comment: Check all the components which you are having in SecondActivity, that must be defined properly with their id in Second Activity.

Comment: I have edited the question and included main_activity.xml file

Comment: just check your button reference in first Activity and all the references in the second activity as there is no issue in the posted code. ya please try the by extending the first activity to Activity class

Comment: you have post `Fragement_main` but you set your layout as `activity_main` move all widget to `activity_main`

Comment: I guess that layout is belongs to fragment i guess so you have to write the listener in fragment class and intialisation also in Fragment class.

Comment: I have not added any code in second activity and also only one button is present. So I don't think reference will be a problem there.

Comment: What's the difference between fragement_main.xml and activity_main.xml, since both of them are created by default. What's the purpose of each of them?

Comment: `fragement_main` used on Fragment class, that I think you don't need that. but `activity_main` used for your Activity class, so as you don't used Fragment you can delete that file and work with `activity_main`, so put your widgets (Button , TextView , ... ) to `activity_main`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This Code:-

package com.example.whyprocastinate;

      import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
      import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.LayoutInflater;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
      import android.widget.Button;

      public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    this.setClickListener();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
  }

  private void setClickListener(){
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSecondActivity();  
        }
    }); 
  }

    private void startSecondActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnterTask.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
 }

 @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  /**
  * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
  */
  public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

                }
            });
        return rootView;
      }
   }

  }
```

Comment: @user2294754

This part of Fragment class use in Activity